# Visual Source Safe Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin

With my new job I HAVE to use visual source safe (yes I know it sucks but there is never time to actually migrate off).
so I went to investigate about an Eclipse plugin, and found only 1 but it doesn't work with 64 bit eclipse or any newer version of eclipse than 3.3 (I think)

So I have set myself up a home project to get this plug-in working.

My question is this...
is there anywhere I can just get a sourcesafe front end from to test the plugin is working from home (obv. I am not going to pay for a copy at home for this project)
or anyway to mock one up?

Comment: Get the VSS install from your NEW job. I mean why not?

Comment: because they don't give away licensed software for use at home (already asked)

Comment: but i can remote desktop, problem solved

Comment: @WendyG This is an old question, I know, but if you’re working at home, surely you’re not doing so on your own computer, right? (That would be excessively subsidizing your employer, and would also introduce security issues.) If you’re working on your employer’s computer, you should be able to get their licenses software on it—if not, they’re not providing you the necessary tools to do your job.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I was planning on doing it on my home PC, as no time in work to do this sort of stuff.  But we moved to SVN before I got anywhere. I think my constant moaning worked "if only we had SVN I could do this easily" etc.